# Adding class to form_dropdown in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

How do I add a class to a form_dropdown in CodeIgniter if I also have a Javascript attached.  Here is my code:

```
$language = array(
                        'select' => 'Select Language',
                        'chinese' => '&#20013;&#25991;',
                        'english' => 'English',
                        'french' => 'Fran&ccedil;ais',
                        'german' => 'Deutsch',
                        'italian' => 'Italiano',
                        'japanese' => '&#26085;&#26412;',
                        'korean' => '&#54620;&#44397;&#50612;',
                        'polish' => 'Polska',
                        'portuguese' => 'Portugu&ecirc;s',
                        'russian' => '&#1056;&#1086;&#1089;&#1089;&#1048&#1070;',
                        'spanish' => 'Espa&ntilde;ol'       
                    );

    $js = 'onChange="this.form.submit()"';              
    echo form_dropdown('language', $language, 'select', $js);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class to the `$js` variable;

```
$js = 'onChange="this.form.submit()" class="myClass"';
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks, Rocket.